# Disadvantages of defining Provider as a global variable in riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I think there is a part of riverpod that defines Providers globally, but the explanation in the official documentation is a bit unclear.

> Do not be frightened by the global aspect of providers. Providers are
> fully immutable.  Declaring a provider is no different from declaring
> a function,  Declaring a provider is no different from declaring a
> function, and providers are testable and maintainable.

Copy this code to clipboard
You say that providers are fully immutable, but it seems to me that there are many possibilities for change, such as updating state.
If it is changed at the time of update, is it may difficult to handle because it is in a global variable and we do not know where the update will come from??

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? It's a bit unclear what you're asking here

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly pointed out, providers are global and mutable, however, in order to change their state, you need to have a `ref` reference. To understand

> where the update will come from

you need to use state management models and build an architecture that suits your needs.